# Combining identical arrays using Perl

Tags: arrays, string, perl

I have an input file that has these following data:

**input.txt**

```
xinstA portA out ctl vcc vss box_cell
xinstB in portB ctl vcc vss box_cell
xinstA in out portA%1 vcc vss box_cell
xinstB porB%1 out ctl vcc vss box_cell
xinstA in out mc1_ctl vcc vss box_cell
...
... may have xinstC, xinstD and so forth
...
```

My desired output would be like this:

```
xinstA portA out portA%1 mc1_ctl vcc vss box_cell
xinstB portB%1 portB ctl vcc vss box_cell
...
... can have xinstC, xinstD and so forth.
...
```

I want to merge lines with the same prefix `xinst` names.
How to implement this using Perl?

Comment: Where is your Perl script ?

Comment: my code is quite long, and the problem I asked is just part of that long script but I can provide it to you if you wish to see it

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site about programmers helping programmers with their problems and collate information as a result. It helps massively if you show some willing by indicating your attempt thus far

Answer (score 0):

The *idea* is to store your data in a [hash](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html), using *xinst* name as key and [arrayref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) of other values as a value.

If you want unique values in the array, you should use another hash instead, using actual values as hash keys and `1` or `undef` as hash values (since they don't matter in this particular case).

If you want help with the actual code, you should provide the actual code, not just a problem.

Comment: my actual code is quite long and not using hash, but i can edit provide it to you.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use a hash. Hashes can only hold unique scalars as keys, which you can take advantage of:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $in, '<', 'in.txt' or die $!;

my %data;
while(<$in>){
    chomp;
    my @split = split(/\s+/);
    $data{$split[0]} = $_;
}

print "$data{$_}\n" foreach sort keys %data;
```

Comment: This one only prints the last two of the list. But thanks for the idea, I have to take a more look on hashes since I am new to this hashes